# Override general Button style

Tags: wpf, xaml

We have a general style in default.xaml, targeting all buttons in our application. Is there a way to override this style, and creating a new button based on the default button?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you want to inherit any existing style use  BasedOn

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}"   x:Key="RedTextBasedOnButton">  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> </Style>
```

this will inherit the default style and new foreground property will apply to the new style

hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the Template of the Button like this

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Button}" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
<Border Padding="10,5,10,5" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="#EFEFEF">
  <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
</Border>
</ControlTemplate>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class Style has property BasedOn and the constructor accepting Style parameter which defines style to be based on.

```
Style boldStyle = new Style(typeof(Button), generalButtonStyle);
```